# Laravel custom filter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I need to be able to access a number of routes only if a condition is met. Else I should not have access to those routes.

I thought this should be done with a filter but I think I'm missing something about how they work.

So this is my filter:

```
Route::filter('my.filter', function()
{
    //some code regarding said condition
    if($mycondition==true){
        //WHAT TO PUT HERE?
    }else{
        //Error message
    }
}
```

And in my routes I will have:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'my.filter'), function()
{
    Route::resource('cities', 'CitiesController');
    //... many more controllers here
});
```

But all the examples I have seen have a redirect inside the filter in the if part. I don't want that, I only want, if the condition in the filter is true, you get to see that url.

Comment: Well the question is, what do you want the user to see if the condition is false? One possibility would be to throw a HTTP 403 Error (Access Denied)...

Comment: yes, that is fine with me, but, how to do that?

Comment: Just a second, i'm gonna write an answer

Comment: You should return `true` if the condition is met within your filter

Comment: Jonathon, whatever I have return in the filter will output on the browser, I don't want that. I want the page for the route.

Comment: In addition, you can then add another route that is called if the filtered route does not get called

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking non-sense! What you can do for example is something like `return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);` or `return Redirect::guest('login');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna have your filter stop further Execution of your routes (and controllers and so on) you have to:

- Return something (e.g. a Redirect)
- or throw an Exception

In Laravel you can do this pretty easily:

```
Route::filter('my.filter', function()
{
    //some code regarding said condition
    if($mycondition==true){
        // here you have to do nothing so you could also flip the if...
    }else{
        App::abort(403);
    }
}
```

[Official Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#http-exceptions)

Little sidenote: As mentioned above in the comment i would flip the if. Like that:

```
Route::filter('my.filter', function()
{
    //some code regarding said condition
    if($mycondition==false){
        App::abort(403);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right here, but abort doesn't work, return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401); did the trick in my case. The return true was messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put anything there, just let the function return void. That will tell laravel that the user is allowed to see the page. You can always put a `return` there yourself to let the user see the page and skip all the following conditions.

When the condition is not met, it is better to redirect the user to a page where you explain why the user isn't able to see the page.

```
Route::filter('my.filter', function()
{
    //some code regarding said condition
    if($mycondition==true){
        return;
    }else{
        //Error message
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you replace `$condition` with a real condition?

Comment: Mmmh, it seems my problem is somewhere else inside the controllers I'm testing, looks like your solution works for the filtering part, just need to solve the other issue.

Comment: No this solution doesn't work like you would expect. A return from a filter is like if you would return something from your route. So to "let the request through" you need to return nothing. if you wanna block it return something or throw an Exception. (see my answer)

Comment: Mmmh, I get The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given. when I do a test with a simpler controller.